# Calling method on array entity and children in ReactiveX

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, reactivex

I want to create an observable from a tree. Each node will generate an observable which depends on the observable of its parent(e.g. via `switchMap`). At each level of the tree, the observables for each children needs to be merged.

I want to convert this code so that it uses observables:

```
interface Request {
    name: string;
    childrens?: Request[];
}

start() {
  this.nextRequests(this.requests);
}

private nextRequests(requests: Requests[]) {
  requests.forEach(request => {
    this.socketService.message(request.name, (res) => {
      if (request.childrens) {
        this.nextRequests(request.childrens, res);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

So this is what I thought it would look like:

```js
interface Request {
    name: string;
    childrens?: Request[];
}

// This isn't right. 
// SocketService.message return a observable, the reponse of the request.
start(requests: Request[]): Observable<any> {
  return from(requests).pipe(switchMap(request => {
      return this.socketService.message(request.name);
    }), concatMap(request => {
    if (request.childrens) {
      return this.start(request.childrens);
    }
    return of(request.name);
  }));
}

const mock: Request[] = [
    {name: 'test1', childrens: [
        { name: 'test4' },
        { name: 'test5' }
    ]},
    { name: 'test2' },
    { name: 'test3' }
];

this.start(mock).subscribe((name) => {
    console.log(`Request ${name} done`);
}, err => { }, () => {
    console.log('Complete');
});
```

And the output will should look like this:

```js
Request test1 done
Request test2 done
Request test3 done
Request test4 done
Request test5 done

Complete
```

But instead I get this:

```
Request test2 done
Request test3 done
Request test4 done
Request test5 done
```

The order of emission between sibling nodes is not important. But parents with children are not printed(`test1`), and the complete callback is never executed. Why is that?

Thanks!

Comment: The `switchMap` is probably the culprit. What about flattening your original tree of requests into a single array before sending them to your socket service?

Comment: Because I need the socket service take ~10 before answering, and I need the response of the test1 before calling test4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the main problem here is that you are not adding the `test1` element as param to

```
if (request.childrens) {
  return this.start(request.childrens);
}
```

It should look like

```
if (request.childrens) {
  return this.start([{name:request.name},...request.childrens]);
}
```

By doing so you will recieve the `test1` in the subscription as first value, otherwise it will never be logged, because it will be kind of filtred by the stream.

### EDIT:

Now there is also BFS-ish demo in the link below

The code looks like this

```js
function startBFS(requests) {
  return merge(from(requests)).pipe(
    mergeMap((x, i) => {
      if (x.children) {
        return concat(of(x), startBFS(x.children));
      } else {
        return of(x);
      }
    })
  );
}
```

Here is a live demo [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jl7v5nvj7v)

Comment: Thank you for your time! Do you think it's possible to send all of the first layers before the children?

Because the socket service take ~10 minutes before answering, and I need the response of the test1 before calling test4. But I can call test1, test2, test3 at the same time, not the children.

I did a [codeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/5vyw2lm2vn) to show what I mean.

Comment: Actually I need to read the graph with more like a BFS algorithm.

Comment: Is it mandatory to complete the first level of the array to dig in?

Comment: Actually, each node takes time to process, and the process of a node must be completed before digging to the node children. But reading the graph must be optimized by starting multiple node processes at the same time.

Comment: I just integrated it into our project, thanks a lot for your help <3